# How to draw under transparent image using JAVA FX 2

Tags: java, animation, graphics, javafx-2, fxml

i'm building a Java FX 2 app wich must show animations under a transparent png image, by drawing rectangles to the "Graphics" of a pane located below an image view containing the image.

After hours of searching, i've found only examples that create a rectangle and then, add it to the scene once. However, i need to paint in a loop (every few milliseconds) and i have no idea how to paint directly to the pane.

I'm using FXML to build the GUI.

It's possible to paint to the graphics of any component in Java FX, in the same way as Swing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Image view have a opacity property....it would make image like a transparent..

try this..i hope it work.

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("example.png"));
ImageView im = new ImageView(img);
im.setOpacity(0.25); /*its similar like transparency */
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pane, you can add a Canvas, then use

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
```

From there, you can paint to the graphics context.

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
//probably would want StackPane to layer imageview ontop of canvas
//otherwise, do your own translations
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
ImageView image = ....;
pane.getChildren().addAll(canvas,image);

GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.fillRect(2,2,120,120);
//etc....
```